# PHP not loading curl module

Tags: php, curl, module, loading

PHP is not loading curl module in FreeBSD. I had compiled PHP with curl shared library & the php binary is linked to `/usr/lib/libcurl.so`.1 when checked with ldd.

When I try to use any of the curl api like `curl_init()`, PHP throws an fatal error unknown function. Not sure what is the problem. Every thing seems to be fine. I even tried adding `extensions = /usr/lib/libcurl.so` in my `php.ini` file but no luck till now. Any suggestions.

Comment: try viewing phpinfo() and check if curl library is included.

Comment: The library is not showing up in phpinfo()

Comment: I have even tried to bind it statically with libcurl.a but does not seams to help. Any way to check whether the php binary is bound with libcurl.a or not. php -m does not show libcurl. I have a diff linux system in which everything compiles fine and when I try php -m it shows curl as one of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling PHP with curl shared library just means you've enabled the ability for PHP to use curl, it doesn't enable it.

You still need to add:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Obviously, make sure you're using the right php.ini file based on whether you're using the command line (cli) or apache/web server php environment.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php

Most linux distributions have a package to handle adding curl to php.

Comment: Also don't forget to set `extension_dir` to the correct path.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_version() in /cf/var/tmp/jail/html/curl.php
I have added the following line to my php.ini extension = "curl.so".
When I do php -m which shows the modules that are loaded it does not show curl but shows the other modules
./php -c ../../etc/php.ini -m
[PHP Modules]
cgi-fcgi
Core
ctype
date
dom
libxml
pcre
posix
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
xml
xsl
zlib

Comment: Can you just use a package through a package manager for your linux distribution? yum/apt-get, etc? Most have a package called php-curl, php4-curl, php5-curl, etc. It would handle all of this for you if you just installed through the package manager.